# If I have a GSM device, with a radio that has common LTE bands between carriers, is it possible to compare available bands and signal strength?

Tags: network-signal, carriers

I'd like to know if it is possible, given that I have devices which can operate on multiple networks, if I can use that device to check the signal strength of a competitor network in the area.

I live in a fairly rural area, and I am frequently on T-Mobile's band 71 LTE, which is admittedly a rural band. I'm paying more than I want to pay, and I'd like to consider switching to an AT&T based MVNO if we can find one that we like. I don't like the options that I have for T-Mobile MVNOs and I'd like to at a minimum do my homework.

1.) We do have some friends here, but I think they are people mostly on our carrier or Verizon, which doesn't work where we live.

2.) We find that the coverage estimators where we live are *very generous to the carrier*. For instance, Verizon insists that they have 4G LTE coverage in our area, but neither my wife's iphone, nor my Note 20 5G could find such coverage. We traded her iphone in and she got an android, and even that device was not great out here. So we think that these things are very inaccurate and biased towards touting the carrier's claims, rather than honest and precise.

We'd appreciate any help you can provide, in the interests of saving any duplicative effort, here's what we know about, and understand options on.

- We know we can buy an old device with it's sim present to use as a test.
- We understand the existence of e-SIM, and the cost to obtain service with one.
- We don't know if any of our friends or church family are with AT&T, A lot of folks here are with T-Mobile.
- We know our phones if they are given a sim from a competitor, will attempt those networks.

Is there any software or ability to check out the RSPP and SINR dB m from other networks while attached to T-Mobile?